# Spring JPA @OneToMany entity of the entity returned by the Repository.save() method is null

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a Post entity and a Comment entity.

It works fine for common CRUD operations.

By the way, a problem arises when manipulating the Post entity returned by save() in the Post repository.

It is stored in the database, but the Comment collection that Post has is null.

Other findBy operations return comments as emptyColletions normally.

How should I fix it?

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
public class Post extends LocalDateTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)     
    private User user;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
public class Comment extends LocalDateTimeEntity {

    @Id                                                      
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String content;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Post post;

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please post whole code of `PostService.save` and `PostService.findById`

Answer (score 0):

From your Comment entity remove ManyToOne for post. Because while saving post you are missing to save/handle comments associated.

So use commentsDto to get associated comments. And use orphan removal as true from Post side.

Take a look at a close match with your requirement on (my) github repo here - https://github.com/ajkr195/ThymeleafDynamicFields